# How to show the latest data in achartengine of Android?

Tags: android, achartengine

I use achartengine to draw some statistics bar graph on my Android application. There will be for example 7 bars within one screen. But the total bars should be quite more. And I want to know how to show the latest 7 bars instead of showing the first 7 bars by default. Could anyone help? Thanks!

Complement:
e.g. I have 100 data/bars (***they are generated one by one with date/time, 1 is the first one and 100 is the last***) as below, but due to limitation of the phone screen size only 7 data/bar are proper to show. By default it shows the first 7 data/bars each time. But I want to let it show the last 7 data/bars so that I can see ***the latest result*** directly.

by default:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 ...95 96 97 98 99 100
-------------
```

if drag the graph:

```
1 2 3 ... 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 .... 97 98 99 100
          --------------------
```

I want it be like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 ...95 96 97 98 99 100
                           ------------------
```

here ------------- means the phone screen.

**I find the answer:**

```
// show the last 7 data/bars
        if(count < 7){
            renderer.setXAxisMin(0.5);
            renderer.setXAxisMax(7.5);
        }
        else
        {           
            renderer.setXAxisMin(count-7+0.5);
            renderer.setXAxisMax(count-7+7.5);  
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

So you have more than 7 values in your series and there are only 7 bars displayed? Sounds like you just set 7 xLabels. As far as I know AChartEngine shows only the amount of set xLabels. So you just have to add some more xLabels. (the amount of bars you want to see in your chart)

Comment: Please check my main post for further explaination. Thank you!